# NGINX / Gunicorn: Return JSON formatted Error Messages

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gunicorn

I'm using NGINX as a reverse-proxy for a gunicorn application server. When there's a server error (url not found, request-timeout, etc) the response is returned as html. I'm familiar with NGINX's [error page directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) and I've attempted to put an error directive in the server block that forwards to my application server as shown below however the response is still returned as html. Any ideas?

```
server {
        server_name rtj.foo.com;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/ubuntu/api;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location /404.html{
            return 404 '{"error": {"status_code": 404,"status": "Not Found"}}';
        }

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the content type for the requested document by adding and empty `types` block and setting `default_type` to `application/json`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for details.

For example:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    types {}
    default_type application/json;
    return 404 '{"error": {"status_code": 404,"status": "Not Found"}}';
}
```

If the URI does not need to be directly accessible (i.e. is private to the `error_page` directive), you could use a named location instead:

```
error_page 404 @error404;
location @error404 {
    types {}
    default_type application/json;
    return 404 '{"error": {"status_code": 404,"status": "Not Found"}}';
}
```

Comment: So that didn't work for me. But if I do something like `location = /test { *your config* }` it works. 

When the request hits the server block it skips over the `location = /404.html` and goes to `location /  {}` which is handled by my application server. If the application server doesn't find the requested resource...it either responds with a 404 or tells nginx to respond with 404. I may need to do more research on this as I'm not sure which server is responding.

Comment: Gunicorn is intercepting the error. If you add `proxy_intercept_errors on;` in the application server's location block it will work.